# Sinatra Heroku app: `start_server': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

So I've been trying all sorts over the past couple of hours hoping I could fix this, but I've caved and have to ask for some help...

I'm trying to deploy a Sinatra-based app to Heroku using PostgreSQL with Datamapper.

Restarting the dyno hasn't helped, and it works fine locally using Shotgun (which appears to be WEBrick 1.3.1).

The Heroku logs:

```
2014-09-15T00:44:16.620710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-09-15T00:44:18.868126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 55219`
2014-09-15T00:44:21.353588+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1497:in `start_server': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)
2014-09-15T00:44:21.353629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1435:in `run!'
2014-09-15T00:44:21.353657+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
2014-09-15T00:44:22.014311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-09-15T00:44:22.005268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-15T00:44:23.532489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=glacial-retreat-7648.herokuapp.com request_id=df6fe1b9-9868-49b0-83e1-fc57dd1c3e63 fwd="86.161.84.51" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Parts of app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'twitter'

...

configure :development do
    DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
end

configure :production do
    DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL'])
end

...

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'twitter'

gem 'dm-aggregates'
gem 'dm-constraints'
gem 'dm-core'
gem 'dm-migrations'
gem 'dm-serializer'
gem 'dm-timestamps'
gem 'dm-types'
gem 'dm-validations'

gem 'data_mapper'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
    gem 'do_sqlite3'

end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'do_postgres'
    gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
end
```

config.ru:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT
```

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: user
  database: development
```

If you have any thoughts whatsoever, I'd be extremely grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that your `Procfile` simply launches the app directly, it is bypassing your `config.ru`. You should probably change it to something like `web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT` (add Thin to your `Gemfile` first).